# Django - when using different databases - should I use "using" or "db_manager"?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

To select a specific database you write either:

```
Object.objects.using('other_db')...
```

or:

```
Object.objects.db_manager('other_db')...
```

Both seem to work completely fine. So what is the difference between both?

**EDIT**

I mean - should I always use the '*db_manager('other_db')*' which would cover all cases for the '*using('other_db')*' statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your situation. If you don't use any [manager method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods) then `using()` is fine, otherwise you will need `db_manager()`.

> You can select the database for a `QuerySet` at any point in the `QuerySet` “chain.” Just call `using()` on the `QuerySet` to get another `QuerySet` that uses the specified database.

But if you need to use manager methods, this will not work.

The following explanation is taken from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#using-managers-with-multiple-databases):

Say you have a custom manager method that touches the database – `User.objects.create_user()`. Because `create_user()` is a manager method, not a `QuerySet` method, you can’t do `User.objects.using('another_db').create_user()`. **The `create_user()` method is only available on `User.objects`, the manager, not on `QuerySet` objects derived from the manager.** The solution is to use `db_manager()`, like this:

```
User.objects.db_manager('another_db').create_user(...)
```

`db_manager()` returns a copy of the manager bound to the database you specify.

Comment: Good answer. 
... So I can almost always use the db_manager instead of 'using' and  worry about nothing.